# Android WorkManager PeriodicWorkRequest repeating too soon

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

```
val repeatedReq = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
            MyWorkerClass::class.java,15,TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(repeatedReq)
```

My WorkManager is calling doWork every 3-6 minutes rather than every 15 minutes like I specified in my code. Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

- Periodic work has a minimum interval of 15 minutes.
- If it runs every 3-6 minutes, you have many workManagers. You forgot
  to cancel the others

Answer (score 3):

As pointed by @Kasim, `PeriodicWorkRequest` has a minimum interval of 15min. if you want to have a [unique](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/unique-work) instance of your request you should use:

```kotlin
val repeatedReq = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorkerClass::class.java,15,TimeUnit.MINUTES).build()

WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("YOURUNIQUENAME", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, repeatedReq)
```

- `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP`: If there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique name, do nothing. Otherwise, insert the newly-specified work.
- `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.REPLACE`: If there is existing pending (uncompleted) work with the same unique name, cancel and delete it. Then, insert the newly-specified work.